# change color text in background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made the background red using clip-path

```
.page:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 0, 0 100%);
max-width: 550px;
height: 950px;
background: #F41B15 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
top: -20px;
z-index: -1;
width: 100%;}
```

I have a piece of gray text, when it overlaps the background, I want it to automatically turn white on every screen

```
.page  p {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 31px;
color : #FFF}
```

This is images
[image]

Comment: Possibly look into the mix-blend-mode css property found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by having a `span` element with the same content as your paragraph and an attirbute `aria-hidden="true"` to avoid accessibility issues, then setting the paragraph position to relative and the `span` position to absolute on the top left, clipping the path of the span with the same path than your `.page:before` and having the text of the `span` with a color of white on top of the text.